# Adding dynamic prompt colors in tcsh

Tags: csh, tcsh

I have a script that I use to update my tcsh prompt.  I would like to add some additional code that would add colors.  However, I would like the colors to differ based on the value of `$dir_str`.  Below is the code in my .cshrc:

```
# Initial set required for 1st prompt in a new window
set dir_str=`update_dir.csh`
# set prompt to use $dir_str
set prompt = '%$dir_str [%c09]%L\n -> '
# aliases for change dir commands to update prompt
alias cd 'chdir \!* && set dir_str="`update_dir.csh`"'
alias pushd 'pushd \!* && set dir_str="`update_dir.csh`"'
alias popd 'popd \!* && set dir_str="`update_dir.csh`"'
```

Here is the code for update_dir.csh.  I'm not actually using env vars (`$in_dev_directory`, etc.), these are actually more complex commands:

```
if ($in_dev_directory) then
  echo "\e[1;34mDEV\e[0m"
else if ($in_prod_directory) then
  echo "\e[1;30mPROD\e[0m"
else
  echo "\e[1;31mNO_PROJ\e[0m"
endif
```

Without any color code information, the prompt updates work as intended.  I have tried echoing the prompt color codes as well, e.g. `echo "%{\033[1;31m%}NO_PROJ%{\033[0m%}"` but that prints the characters (no color).  Running the update script stand-alone prints the string in the desired color.  **Any ideas on how to update the prompt color based on the directory?**

Side note: I'm using the directory change aliases because alias cwdcmd kept giving me "command not found" errors (even with full paths).  Also, I'm stuck with tcsh (no zsh, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working using `set prompt = '%{%$prompt_color_str%}%B%$prompt_dir_str%b%{\033[0m%} [%c09]%L\n -> '` where `$prompt_color_str` is generated via a shell script that echoes `"^[[0;31m"` (or desired color code). Note that the `^[` is the escape character (not a caret-bracket). I also updated my chdir aliases to run the additional script.